# Android CalendarView detect month change

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I was wondering if there was a way for me to detect when a user changes the month (swipes to another month). Right now, I've implemented a

`calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(this);`

My problem is that, when I change the month, the

`@Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`

fires, but the year, month and day that I get is still the selected date from the month where I came from.

Am I missing something here? Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: i also want the same feature did you find the answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot implement the month change event using Android's default CalenderView. However, an alternative customized MaterialCalendarView is available [here](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/) that provides both the date and month change listeners.

The sample code to use the view is as follows:

```
MaterialCalendarView calendarView = new MaterialCalendarView(getActivity());
calendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
 @Override
 public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
        // Do something here
        Date selectedDate = date.getDate();
 }
});
```

The date change listener can also be implemented in the similar manner using MaterialCalendarView.

Comment: Looks like the library has not been maintained in a while.